# Extraer la cantidad de lunes del mes actual PHP

Tags: php, date

Necesito extraer la cantidad de lunes que haya en el mes actual, para lograr hacer algunos cálculos para las nominas de trabajadores, comenze con este fragmento donde recorro la fechas ingresadas y me muestra las fechas de cada lunes, pero necesito que sea del mes actual, y solo el numero de lunes, no la fecha entera

```
<?php 
$fechaInicio=strtotime("2019-06-01");
$fechaFin=strtotime("2019-06-30"); 
//Recorro las fechas y con la función strotime obtengo los lunes
for($i=$fechaInicio; $i<=$fechaFin; $i+=86400 * 7){
  echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week', $i))."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PHP existen funciones que nos devuelven el número total de días de un mes de un año en específico, esto es **cal_days_in_month**, ahora, para calcular cuántos lunes, martes, etc. existen en ese mes podemos recorrer cada día del mes y compararlo con el número del día de la semana.

Con la siguiente función puedes calcular el número de días que contiene un mes de cualquier año (siempre y cuando exista en CAL_GREGORIAN):

```
<?php
function cuenta_dias($mes,$anio,$numero_dia)
{
    $count=0;
    $dias_mes=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $anio);
    for($i=1;$i<=$dias_mes;$i++)
    if(date('N',strtotime($anio.'-'.$mes.'-'.$i))==$numero_dia)
    $count++;
    return $count;
}

// 1 - lunes
// 2 - martes
// 3- miercoles
// ..
// 7 - domingo
echo cuenta_dias(06,2019,1);
```